# Does increasing the machine precision automatically raise terms in series expansion?

Tags: c, floating-point, precision, series, expansion

I was wondering if increasing the machine precision from **float** to **double** in **C** automatically raise terms in series expansion e.g. trigonometric functions ?

This and my other questions on stack overflow has to do with investigating occurring numerical instability on a wave equation in anisotropic media.

Comment: I don't think so. C++ has the concept of function overloading, so the compiler knows what form of the function to call depending on the type of the argument. I don't believe this concept exists in C. If you call the function with a `float` it will be converted to double before the calculation is performed. I will look for a reference to confirm...

Comment: @Floris `float` doesn't automatically promote to `double` as `char` and `short` promote to `int`.

Comment: Trigonometric functions are single machine instructions since the introduction of 80387...

Comment: @n.m.: Indeed.  But if you look at the machine code emitted by the compiler, you'll probably see that it doesn't use them.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: it depends on your compiler flags. If you want fast math, not strictly IEEE conforming but fast, the compiler will use these commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, what affects the accuracy of routines to perform sine, logarithm, and so on is which version of the routine you call. A good math library has separate routines for single-precision sine (C’s `sinf` function), double-precision sine (C’s `sin`), and long-double sine (C’s `sinl`). In C, you usually call these versions explicitly, by writing calls to `sinf`, `sin`, or `sinl`. C also offers `<tgmath.h>`, which causes the source code `sin(x)` to expand to a specific version depending on the type of `x`. In C++, a function call will also be resolved depending on the type of the variable.

In a good math library, the `sinf` routine will use a faster algorithm with accuracy suited to the precision of `float`, while `sin` will use a slower algorithm suited to the precision of `double`. The quality of math libraries varies, as writing these routines is a complicated task.

Series expansion is not used. (In particular, Taylor series are not used due to poor error distribution and requiring too many terms to converge.) Instead, carefully prepared approximating polynomials are used. Some form of minimax polynomial is often used. A routine for a more precise type is likely to use a polynomial with more terms, but it is also likely to change in other ways, such as partitioning the domain into more intervals or using some form of extended precision. None of this is automatic; the routines are prepared manually by software enginers.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/sin/), while there are different versions of the `sin(x)` function for C++,

> In C, only the double version of this function exists with this name

To confirm this, I wrote the following lines of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void){

    double d = 0.12345e16;
    float f;
    f = d;

    printf("the difference is %f\n", sin(d) - sin(f));

    f = 0.12345e16;
    d = f;
    printf("the difference is now %f\n", sin(d) - sin(f));

}
```

This produces the following output (when compiled with the C compiler):

```
the difference is 1.947785
the difference is now 0.000000
```

EDIT - had a typo in my original code. Now updated, and giving the expected result.

The above shows that the two arguments are evaluated the same way, confirming that the same algorithm is used.

This is using the gcc compiler on Linux, with the `-lm` option, and with the file called `fltchk.c` (which I believe should cause gcc to use the C compiler).

Comment: The reason this code shows a difference between `sin(d)` and `sin(f)` in the first case is because it is taking the sine of two different numbers; they differ by 33,970,176. The assignment `f = d;` converts the value of `d` to `float`, which changes it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - yes: this is why I did the assignment in two different directions. You lose precision in the `f=d` assignment, but not in the `d=f` assignment; so if you use the same (large) number and get the same answer, you know it used the same algorithm (it converted `f` to `double` before the calculation).